# Java wildcards - generics creating Arrays.asList or ImmutableList.of

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, guava

I have just came accross a question which I don't quite understand.
I have following variable (class field):

```
List<Validator<?, Data>> validators;
```

Now I want to assign some validators' instances to this list, then:

```
validators = Arrays.asList(validatorsFactory.create(Obj1.class));
```

Where the create method returns `Validator<?, Data>`
And there is a problem: I need to specify generic type of that list, due to wildcards. Okay, right version is:

```
validators = Arrays.<Validator<?, Data>>asList(validatorsFactory.create(Obj1.class));
```

But, when I add two elements instead of one I dont have to specify any generic type. How does Java know that the wildcards are the same?

```
validators = Arrays.asList(
    validatorsFactory.create(Obj1.class), validatorsFactory.create(Obj2.class)
);
```

My understanding of that was that all wildcards are different placeholders when they are an arguments to a method. 
Same applies to Guava's: `ImmutableList.of`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the signature of `validatorsFactory.create` method?

Comment: sure: __public <V extends Validator<?, D>, D extends Data> Validator<?, D> getValidator(Class<V> validatorClass)__

Comment: What is `getValidator`? Is it the `create` method you are using in the post?

Comment: yes, right, thats just the real name of it :) sorry

Comment: Are you getting a compile-time error or a warning when you do `validators = Arrays.asList(validatorsFactory.create(Obj1.class));`?

Comment: Just passing one element to `Arrays.asList` without specifying the generic type is working for me

Comment: yes, it is a compile time error, specifically: __Incompatible types: required List<Validator<?, Data>> but found List<Validator<capture<?>, Data>>__

Answer (score 0):

When you have an argument with a wildcard at the top level, e.g. `Validator<?, Data>`, you are allowed to pass it to a generic method with a type variable in the place where the wildcard is, e.g. `public <T> void foo(Validator<T, Data>)`. This is called wildcard capture.

This case is a little different, because the `Arrays.asList()` takes parameters of type `T`. For some reason in your first case, it is keeping the capture when inferring the type of `T`, so it infers `T` to be `Validator<capture #XXX, Data>`, which is not the `T` that you want.

In your second case, I am guessing that the fact you have two arguments, both of type `Validator<?, Data>`, somehow makes it impossible for `T` to be inferred to contain a capture, since the two wildcards would have two different captures, so it just infers `T` to be `Validator<?, Data>`, which is what you wanted in the first place.